# Happens Before relationship in the same thread

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic, stdatomic

I am reading the book "[C++ Concurrency in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action-second-edition)" section 5.3 on Memory Model of C++ and listing 5.5 below confuses me:

```
std::atomic<bool> x,y;
std::atomic<int> z;
void write_x_then_y()
{
   // Is there a Happens-Before relationship for statement (1) and (2) below?
   x.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed); // --> (1)
   y.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed); // --> (2)
}
void read_y_then_x()
{
   while(!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
   if(x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
   ++z;
}

int main()
{
    x=false;
    y=false;
    z=0;
    std::thread a(write_x_then_y);         std::thread b(read_y_then_x);
    a.join();
    b.join();
    assert(z.load()!=0);
}
```

What confuses me is function **void write_x_then_y()**. The author says "This time the assert at the end of main() can **fire**" and statement (1) on atomic variable **x** has a "happens-before" relationship with statement (2) on atomic variable **y**. But I thought with **std::memory_order_relaxed**, there is no synchronization between *different* atomic variables, and compiler/CPU can reorder these two statements without violating the program semantics.

> The happensbefore
> relationships from listing 5.5 are shown in figure 5.4, along with a possible outcome.
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An evaluation which is *sequenced-before* another evaluation also *happens-before* it.

*Sequenced-before* is a relation between evaluations in the same thread and independent of synchronization mechanism like e.g. atomic load/stores with non-relaxed memory orders.

*Happens-before* just extends the *sequenced-before* relation for evaluation order from the single-threaded case to the multi-threaded case by incorporating synchronization mechanisms between threads.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order for exact definitions.

An evaluation in one statement preceding another statement is always *sequenced-before* the latter. (Basically there is a *sequence point* between two statements, although that term is not used anymore since C++11.)

---

The compiler can reorder the two relaxed stores. That doesn't affect the *happens-before* relation though. Just because two stores (on different atomics) *happen-before* one another does not imply that the stores can't be observed in a different order by another thread, as demonstrated by the example in the diagram.

You would need to establish a *happens-before* relation between the loads and stores to prevent the shown outcome. And for that inter-thread ordering in some way is required, e.g. via release/acquire atomic operations. Basically, you would need to establish some arrow betweeen the gray boxes in the diagram.

Comment: I actually read the [sequenced before](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) page. Is rule 1) ("Each value computation and side effect of a full expression is sequenced before each value computation and side effect of the next full expression, where a full expression is...") corresponding to your "An evaluation in one statement following another statement is always sequenced-before the latter." ? The official language rule is too formal for me to interpret :(

Comment: @Rich Yes, the quoted rule is wider though. A statement can potentially contain many full-expressions, for each of which the sequencing would apply, and some full-expressions are not directly part of a statement. What you are quoting is the more technical correct wording.

Comment: @Rich I actually wrote it the wrong way around. Of course the statement _preceding_ (not _following_) another _happens-before_ the latter.

Comment: Ah yeah. In my mind I've read _preceding_  :). Ok so how does compiler re-ordering fit into this "sequenced before" relationship? So semantically statement (1) is sequenced before (2) and as I understood it, statement (1) should be evaluated before (2) as well. But compiler is free to emit instructions violating this sequence? So on the thread executing that function, it can observe the stores happening in reverse order?

Comment: @Rich _Happens-before_ just enforces an ordering between side effects and value computations on same scalar objects between the two evaluations. But `(1)` and `(2)` don't operate on the same scalar at all, so there isn't actually anything that the relation enforces. The order of emitted instructions is not really relevant when talking about the behavior of the abstract machine. Even without instruction reordering there is nothing requiring that threads generally agree about the order of stores to different atomics (although most hardware architectures do have such a property).

Comment: I think the point that you're hung up on is can you observe violation of the sequenced-before on the single thread it's happening on? No. The compiler can only rearrange if it can prove you aren't actually looking.

Comment: @JeffGarrett Did you mean to @Rich? Or what are you referring to specifically?

Comment: Sorry, yes that was directed at @Rich. Thought it might help to say it a different way.

Comment: @JeffGarrett So in this case, compiler can prove that I am not actually looking in that function and compiler is free to reorder this sequenced(happens) before relationship b/c as user17732522 commented the statements operate on different atomics and no enforcement is needed. Is my understanding correct? btw really appreciate both of you for all this rich information!